# Identity Server - unsupported_grant_type

Tags: c#, oauth, identityserver4

I have the following client:

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "clientOne",

                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                IncludeJwtId = true,

                // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

                // secret for authentication
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret12345".Sha256())
                },
                RedirectUris = new []
                {
                    "https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback"
                },
                // scopes that client has access to
                AllowedScopes = { "api"},

            }
```

From my understanding when I use HybridAndClientCredentials as the grant type I should be able to specify a username and password when making a request to `/connect/token`

This is my current request via postman:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I've tried the grant type as Hybrid, HybridAndClientCredentials and the outcome is the same "unsupported_grant_type"

Within the logs I get

> No validator is registered for the grant type{"grantType": "hybrid"},

Can anyone spot what I might be doing wrong?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SAiu.png

Comment: Have you checked the Identity Server logs? The usually point to the exact problem.

Comment: I did, I also forgot to add the log to the question too.  I've updated the question with the log information

Answer (score 3):

please try this hybrid client config, and also add custom grant type to handle this flow
https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/aspnetcore2/topics/grant_types.html

I created this client my side its working fine
this is postman request

POST /connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5001
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 140

username=administrator%40templatefirm.com&password=******&client_id=hybrid_check%20&client_secret=******&grant_type=client_credentials

also here ClientGrantTypes table data of this hybrid flow
[image]

Comment: removing username and password the request still works.   client_credentials isn't validating against a user, instead it's more server to server which is not what I want.

Comment: ok ya its working fine. 
so you want this with js client request ?

Comment: Ideally I just want to validate against a username and password, I've been able to achieve this by using `ResourceOwnerPassword` grant type, but it says in the docs this: "There might be reasons for certain legacy or first-party integration scenarios, where this grant type is useful, but the general recommendation is to use an interactive flow like implicit or hybrid for user authentication instead."

Comment: I don't want the user to navigate away from the web app nor mobile, so I think I'll have to use `ResourceOwnerPassword ` to achieve the functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: ya awesome ResourceOwnerPassword  flow perfect to achieve username and password validation.

Comment: also check this may be this is helpful to you 
https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/aspnetcore1/quickstarts/5_hybrid_and_api_access.html